# Error en Godot Engine 4 al querer usar la función "on _area2d_entered()"

Tags: godot-engine

Estoy haciendo un juego en Godot Engine 4, y al querer probar el juego en debug, me daba un error que no me mostraba antes, y es que yo en mi juego puse trampas, que son un `area2d` y para que el jugador muriera la función `on_body_entered` tenia que ser correcta, aquí el código que utilicé:

func _on_pincho_body_entered(body):

```
print_debug("prueba")
```

Al momento de iniciar el modo DEBUG, el código por alguna razón se alteraba y  ponía en la Salida de el depurador el mensaje "prueba", como si el jugador estuviera tocando la hitbox de la trampa, cuando realmente no lo está.

Aquí un video de como sucedió esto:

https://www.veed.io/view/b4a097ae-cc7e-4b8e-a3e3-a3410c7db810?panel=share